# How can I make gallery slideshow width fit to picture width?

Tags: gallery

I am using WordPress 3.8 and I want to make gallery width to fit image width.How can I do that? Currently it look like this:
[image]
I want it look like this:
[image]

Comment: I am inspecting the page with Firefox dev tools. Trying to change css.

Comment: CSS related questions are mostly off-topic, you might get better (or actually any) answer on the main stackexchange. You should also provide a URL if you want people to be able to see your CSS and HTML